# Formato numerico con separador de miles en laravel

Tags: laravel, formato, numberformat

Tengo el siguiente código en un controlador de laravel, es para un gráfico de Chartjs en Vuejs, lo estoy implementando para mostrar un gráfico que indique el gasto mensual de los insums.

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{   $idmes = $request->idmes;

    $motoniveladoras=DB::table('detalle_salidas as s')
    ->where('s.idtipocentro','=','1')
    ->where('s.idfamiliacentro','=','8')
    ->where('s.estado','=','recepcionado')
    ->leftjoin('centros','s.idcentro','=','centros.id')
    ->leftjoin('bodegaarticulos','s.idarticulo','=','bodegaarticulos.id','bodegaarticulos.nombrearticulo')
    ->select(DB::raw('MONTH(s.fecha) as mes'),
             DB::raw('YEAR(s.fecha) as anio'),
             DB::raw(('SUM(s.neto) as total')),
             DB::RAW('s.kilometraje'),
             DB::RAW('((SUM(s.neto)-(s.neto))/(max(s.horometro)-min(s.horometro))) as hrfinal'),
             'centros.nombre as nombre_centro','s.idcentro')
             ->whereNotIn('bodegaarticulos.nombrearticulo',['diesel'])
    ->whereMonth('s.fecha','like', '%'. $idmes . '%')
    ->orderBy('centros.nombre')
    ->groupBy('s.idcentro')
    ->get();
}
```

en el cual necesito que el `DB::raw(('SUM(s.neto) as total'))` me aparesca con separadores de miles ya que al visualizarlo me aparece si separadores.

A continuacion dejo el metodo que implemente para mostrar los valores del gráfico.

```
getMaquinarias(){

        let me=this;


    var url=this.ruta + '/dashboardmaquianria2?idmes=' +   me.idmes;

        axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
            var respuesta= response.data;
            me.arrayMotoniveladoras = respuesta.motoniveladoras;
            //cargamos los datos del chart
            me.loadMaquinarias();


        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },

loadMaquinarias(){
        let me=this;
        me.arrayMotoniveladoras.map(function(x){

            me.varMesMaquinaria.push(x.nombre_centro);
            me.varTotalMaquinaria.push(x.total);


        });


         var      maquinaria=document.getElementById('motoniveladoras').getContext('2d');


        window.maquinaria = new Chart(maquinaria, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: me.varMesMaquinaria,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'COSTO',
                    data: me.varTotalMaquinaria,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 42, 0.5)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 42, 0.5)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

    },
```

En este gráfico necesito que me aparezcan los separadores de miles ya que  visualmente es muy difícil leer el numero.

Answer (score 1):

Para eso puedes utilizar la función [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) de php al momento de visualizar el valor:

```
{{ number_format($motoniveladoras['total'], 2) }}
```

En el ejemplo anterior asumo que lo utilizarás en blade y que mostrarás dos dígitos decimales con el separador punto (.)

En caso que lo uses muy frecuentemente, podrías crear un helper en Laravel, para no tener que copiar este código por todas partes.

Answer (score 0):

Hola muchas gracias lo estoy haciendo en `vuejs` es un gráfico `chartjs`, dejo el código:

```
getMaquinarias(){

    let me = this;
    var url=this.ruta + '/dashboardmaquianria2?idmes=' + me.idmes;
    axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var respuesta= response.data;
        me.arrayMotoniveladoras = respuesta.motoniveladoras;
        //cargamos los datos del chart
        me.loadMaquinarias();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
},

loadMaquinarias(){
    let me = this;
    me.arrayMotoniveladoras.map(function(x){
        me.varMesMaquinaria.push(x.nombre_centro);
        me.varTotalMaquinaria.push(x.total);
    });

    var maquinaria = document.getElementById('motoniveladoras').getContext('2d');
    window.maquinaria = new Chart(maquinaria, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: me.varMesMaquinaria,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'COSTO',
                        data: me.varTotalMaquinaria,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 42, 0.5)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 42, 0.5)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: esto es una respuesta a tu pregunta?

Comment: respondi con otra pregunta

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es espacio para exponer dudas, si requieres ampliar tu publicación original entonces dale en **editar** y añade lo que haga falta